# Excel - replace words automatically

Tags: excel

I don't know if what I'll be asking can be done but I hope so.

I follow races and after each seassion there is a table showing the standing of the drivers and teams. For a weekend, there are 5 tables.

For each session, I copy the table, paste it into excel and import it on my website to desplay it as a table. But before I do that, I have to rename the drivers and teams names (always the same in all tables) to another language and then import the file.

This process takes few minutes, like 5 minutes. 5*5 tables: 25 minutes for a weekend. So I wondering if there 's a trick in a software or excel that could replace all the words I want with other words automatically? that could save me a lot of time.

So next time I post the table into excel, I see the drivers' name automatically in my language, thus I can import the table without edit it and waste few minutes.

I really appreciate your help and hope I can have a positive answer from this community.

Thanks!

Comment: Your website imports the .xls file? Or is it just a "step"? (I mean, you copy, paste into excel, copy again, paste into a .txt and you website imports the .txt.)

Comment: Also, is the table always in the same format? Are the drivers and teams names always in the same column? In the columns where they appear, is there another data (I mean, are their values A1->"Driver1's Name", A2->"Driver2's Name", etc. Or: A1->"something Driver1's Name something else", A2->"blabla Driver2's Name yada yada".)

Comment: I import it directly to my website, but I can use Excel if there's a trick to automatically replace the words. 

No they are not on the same rows..It depends on their results. But yeah Teams and drivers are on the same column but different row each time.

Comment: You say "I import it directly to my website". What is "it"? The Excel `.xls` file?

Comment: @user2145957: Do you have a list of words which needs to be replaced and also a list with which it needs to be replaced with? If yes then we can use an Excel Macro to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Siddarth: Yeah Sure.

What I do is I copy the table from here:

http://www.planetsport.com/live/f1/

Example for Fernando Alonso the translation is فرناندو ألونسو

Answer (score 0):

I fear there may be more required than relatively simple lookup formulae but for want of any other answer so far and focussing on your title, please try:

```
 =VLOOKUP(B2,drivers,2,0)
```

in E2 for the example below, and copy down to suit. This assumes you have an array as in the box in the middle named `drivers` (need not be in same sheet) and that ColumnD is a copy of ColumnA.

Similarly in G2:

```
=VLOOKUP(C2,team,2,0)
```

where the right-hand box is an array named `team`, and ColumnC is after relocation.

[image]